# Handling multipart/form-data in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a request with an image to a lambda function through API gateway.

I'm using this [piece of code](https://github.com/myshenin/aws-lambda-multipart-parser/blob/master/index.js) to parse the form-data-object received by my lambda function. I then upload the image to S3, but when downloading and opening the image from S3, I see that it's corrupt.

I have tried the following npm packages:

- [parse-multipart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart)
- [parse-multipart-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart-data)

Both do not work, because I get an empty parts-array. The piece of code I use does get results in the array, but the buffers seems to be corrupt.

The problem seems to be in this line of code:

```
Buffer.from(item.slice(item.search(/Content-Type:\s.+/g) + item.match(/Content-Type:\s.+/g)[0].length + 4, -4), 'binary')
```

Does anyone has a solution for me?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) to parse the multipart form data before uploading to S3 as shown below:

```js
// This code is written in ECMAScript 6 (ES6), not CommonJS syntax.
// So, make sure you add <"type": "module"> in your package.json.
import {S3Client, PutObjectCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import Busboy from 'busboy';

// Initialize the clients outside the function handler to take advantage of execution environment reuse.
const s3Client = new S3Client({region: process.env.AWS_REGION});

// Function handler.
export async function handler(event) {
    const {
        ContentType: contentType = '',
        File: file = '',
    } = await FORM.parse(event['body'], event['headers']);

    try {
        // Adds an object to a bucket. We must have `WRITE` permissions on a bucket to add an object to it.
        await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand({
            Body: file,
            Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
            ContentType: contentType,
            Key: 'SOME_KEY',
        }));

        return {
            isBase64Encoded: false,
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Everything is gonna be alright.',
            }),
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            isBase64Encoded: false,
            statusCode: 404,
            body: JSON.stringify(e),
        }
    }
}

const FORM = {
    parse(body, headers) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const data = {};
            const buffer = Buffer.from(body, 'base64');
            const bb = Busboy({
                headers: Object.keys(headers).reduce((newHeaders, key) => {
                    // busboy expects lower-case headers.
                    newHeaders[key.toLowerCase()] = headers[key];
                    return newHeaders;
                }, {}),
                limits: {
                    fileSize: 10485760, // Set as desired.
                    files: 1,
                },
            });

            bb.on('file', (name, stream, info) => {
                const chunks = [];

                stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    if (name === 'File') {
                        chunks.push(chunk);
                    }
                }).on('limit', () => {
                    reject(new Error('File size limit has been reached.'));
                }).on('close', () => {
                    if (name === 'File') {
                        data[name] = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                        data['ContentType'] = info.mimeType;
                    }
                });
            });
            bb.on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
            bb.on('close', () => {
                resolve(data);
            });

            bb.end(buffer);
        });
    }
};
```